# How many ways can x and y people be arranged in z seats arranged in a circle? If z > x + y and y arrive after x

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

For the question

*How many ways can x and y people be arranged in z seats if z > x + y and y people arrive after x?*
I got (zCx)*((z-x)Cy) if we only want to count combinations, but (zCx)x!((z-x)Cy)y! if we want permutations. The reason being is we can think of it as counting separate experiments. One being x people choosing z seats then y people choosing z - x seats because x of the z seats are taken.

*How many ways can they be seated in a circle?:*
This is the one I'm not sure of cause circular permutation on wolfram says the solution is (n-1)! for arranging n distinct objects. I'm not really sure how to apply this to the solution above. If my solution to the above is incorrect do let me know as well.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the answer was (zCx)(zCy)/z. Working under the assumption that the people in x and y are indistinguishable like the chairs. Then there are z possible rotations to get rid of.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the condition of $y$ people choosing seats after $x$ is actually irrelevant; all possible seatings are equally likely regardless of this condition. So we wish to find the number of ways to seat $x+y$ people at a table with $z$ seats. Since rotations are identical, we find the number of seatings of people $2$ to $x+y-1$ relative to the first person, yielding a total $^{z-1} P_{x+y-1}$.

Comment: Why are they equally likely regardless of y choosing after x? I'd assume since x chose first, then y could only choose from the remaining z - x seats.

Comment: @DylanYung Consider the $z$ seats; these seats are all identical and so if any arrangement was more likely than another you’d contradict symmetry.

Comment: I see. Is z−1Px+y−1 you posted supposed to be (z-1) choose (x+y-1) btw?

Comment: It’s P because I’m assuming people are distinguishable. If they weren’t, it’d be choose.